Jenkins pipeline can't push the image
I faced an issue with my Jenkins pipeline. This pipeline have worked for a long time. After that it started to fail with the auth to docker registry error.
unauthorized: User is unauthorized to upload to docker-registry/kong/k/_uploads

There were no changes made in the pipeline. So maybe anyone has an idea what's wrong with the pipeline below?
// scripted pipeline
// script properties with input parameters.Version as string input parameter
properties([
  parameters([
    string(defaultValue: 'latest', description: '', name: 'tag', trim: false)
    ])
])

def registry = [
    url : 'docker-registry-url',
    credentials: "creds"
]

node('dockerhost'){
    stage('checkout'){
        cleanWs()
        checkout scm
    }
    stage('build'){
        // check if file kong_v.txt exists
        if(fileExists(file: 'kong_v.txt')){
            docker.image('python:3.9').withRun() { c ->
                sh "pip3 install jinja2 pyyaml schema"
                sh "python3 generate_dockerfile.py > Dockerfile"
            }
            // parse file, split by new line, filter out comments and empty strings.
            def kong_versions = readFile('kong_v.txt').split('\n').findAll{line -> 
                line.startsWith('#') == false && line.isEmpty() == false
            }
            // for each kong version build docker image
            kong_versions.each{kong_version -> 
                kong_version = kong_version.trim()
                withDockerRegistry(url:"https://$registry.url" ,credentialsId:"$registry.credentials"){
                    sh "docker build --build-arg=KONG_VERSION=$kong_version -t $registry.url/kong/kong-$k:$tag ."
                    sh "docker push $registry.url/kong/kong-$k:$tag"
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("kong_v.txt file not found")
        }
    }
}


That would be an issue with the registry, or the image repository.

Most likely your auth token has expired.

Thanks to all! It was an issue related to expired registry credentials stored in Jenkins secret. It was fixed after refreshing credentials.
